# How to upgrade a server from 12.04 to 16.04?

Tags: server

The machine has no desktop, only a command shell. It is running 12.04. I have been doing apt-get update & upgrade weekly for four years. How do I convert it to 16.04 from the command line? I have a 16.04 server install CD, do I boot from that?

Comment: What have you followed that didn't work? Did you tried http://askubuntu.com/q/110477/169736?

Answer (score 17):

### General

You can always upgrade from LTS to LTS, in your case that would mean:

- upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 and then
- upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

As far as i know there is no supported upgrade from 12.04 to 16.04 directly.

Following this approach there is no need for your 16.04 medium

As always, consider creating a backup of your critical files before you start.

### Limit to LTS

The way to limit upgrades to LTS without a GUI is to change the value of  `Prompt` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.

Set it to

```
[DEFAULT] Prompt=lts
```

The possible values are

- **never:** Never check for a new release.
- **normal:** Check to see if a new release is available. If more than one new release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running release.
- **lts:** Check to see if a new LTS release is available. The upgrader will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after the currently-running one. Note that this option should not be used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to determine if a newer release is available

### How to upgrade

For both upgrade processes you should always update the current system via

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then start the upgrade via

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

or - SPECIAL CASE - for development versions (which is valid for upgrades from 14.04 to 16.04 until 16.04.1 was released):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

If `do-release-upgrade` command is not found, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that the LTS to LTS for 14.04 to 16.04 won't be enabled until 16.04.1, several months from now.

Comment: @ThomasW.: true, while it still works already if you are using -d

Comment: True, but it's hard to determine that from your post, hence the comment.

Comment: Good point , i updated the post slightly

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, I must edit
`/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`
to change Prompt to
`[DEFAULT] Prompt=lts`

Then reboot and give these commands:

```
sudo bash
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

{Reboot again}

```
sudo bash
do-release-upgrade -c
```

{check target version}

```
do-release-upgrade
```

{I can upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 now;
upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 may have to wait until August}

=========

I asked a question about how to upgrade a server from 12.04 to 16.04. I got many leads, links to other sites, etc. Finally, I posted my own answer - the specific commands I must give to do it. My posted answer was gleaned from reading all the other answers.

Every answer has a rating. I assume higher numbers are better. I see that my summary answer has a rating of minus one. I assume this is worse than zero. How did I earn a minus one rating?

> Note: all three of my computers already read  "Prompt=lts"